# Capture Identifier from Google Forms to Match to E-Blast

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Need to send a Google Forms survey to a few thousand clients of mine based on an email list I have internally. As a segment of this list, the only identifier I have is email to match back to my CRM. I thought to request an email but have concerns if the enterprise email in my CRM is "partnerships@somewebsite.com" but the individual who responds to the form may write "john@somewebsite.com" which I could not match back directly. There is high potential for users to be operating on gmail without domains (company@gmail.com in CRM, joe@gmail.com is email input) so matching to domain is risky. I can pre-populate the field using Google Form's methods but if I do multiple-choice, I can't add a variable based on the Pre-Filled Links option. If I make a string, they can go through the flow above trying to add themselves as primary POC when they shouldn't be according to agreements.

Anyone aware of a way to capture a unique identifier I can match to the email I send so that it is populated on my Google Sheets responses?

Workflow is:

- Email sent from internal service using list of client emails
- Client user executes on email link to Google Forms
- Input ~3-5 survey questions
- Submits
- (problem) I need a way map submission 1 = 1 to the enterprise submitting based off their corporate email logged in our database.

I need an identifier on response needed to match back to the Enterprises' email that I will have pre-populated on my response sheet in a separate tab

Comment: Hi there @CtoM2020! Could you please share the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you are using so that we can better help you? And please remember to remove or anonymize any private information.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron I haven't gotten that far yet, still trying to scope out how to make this work. Google Forms provides the functionality for a pre-filled URL where I need to ensure that the pre-filled variable does not change.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question context. I get that you send a survey Form by mail to multiple users. The goal is to save those surveys by their corporate email, but some users will fill the Form from a different email than their corporate counterpart. Did I understand that correctly? If that is correct, then you may want to include a bonus question to ask users about their corporate email if they logged in from a different one. I recommend you to [collect respondents' email addresses](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139706) to prevent misuse.